# What is the meaning of "zuverlässiger"?

Tags: word-usage

I know already that it means reliable, so that we can say:

> Er ist ein zuverlässiger Mensch.

But I read this sentence:

> In den USA gibt es im Winter nur selten Schnee. Da ist es in den Alpen schon ***zuverlässiger***.

I dont unterstand how Snow in the Alps can be more reliable than in USA.

Comment: @AndrejaKo is completely correct, but there is also an error in your (OP) question. Following sentence is not correct in German: “In den USA Schnee gibt es im Winter nur selten.” A correct Variant would be: “In den USA gibt es im Winter nur selten Schnee.” ``es`` is the subject of the sentence and ``geben`` is the predicate. Because of the adverb in the beginning, they change their positions. ``Schnee`` is the object (what is there?).

Comment: Sieht aus wie ein Zitat, daher korrigiere ich es nicht. "In den USA gibt es im Winter nur selten Schnee." "In den USA gibt es nur selten Schnee im Winter." "Es gibt nur selten Schnee in den USA im Winter/im Winter in den USA."

Comment: Jetzt habe ich es doch korrigiert. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the first sentence explains that in the USA, during the winter, it rarely snows. The “Schnee gibt es” part would literally mean that there is snow.

In the second sentence, it explains that the occurrence of “snowing” is more reliable. So, according to the author, you can “rely” more on having snow in the Alps than in the USA.

Comment: Excatly. They use the word "zuverlässig" because a tourist, booking his winter holidays in a skiing resort, relies on that snow.

Answer (score 1):

**zuverlässig=reliable**

But in this case it means: **more likely** (a bad translation would be **more reliable**)

So the scene means: 
(Made some correction, because it was not completely correct)

> In den USA gibt es im Winter nur selten Schnee. Da ist es in den Alpen schon zuverlässiger.

Literally:

> In the US there is seldom snow in winter. In the Alps there is a bigger reliability.

"Reliability" refers to the chance of snow.

Comment: Es - das Schnee?

Comment: Es - dass es Schnee gibt.

Answer (score 0):

> In den USA gibt es im Winter nur selten Schnee. Da ist **er** in den
>   Alpen schon zuverlässiger.

Schnee ist maskulinum. Er, der Schnee, ist in den Alpen schon zuverlässiger.

Der Vergleich Alpen/USA ist allerdings verwirrend, hier ein Gebirge, dort ein Staat. Ein Vergleich der Appalachen oder der Rockys mit den Alpen wäre wohl eher angemessen, oder der USA mit Frankreich, Italien, der Schweiz, Österreich oder Deutschland.

Aber natürlich kann man statistisch auch Regionen vergleichen und sich entweder an den schneesichersten Orten der USA orientieren.

Davon abgesehen kann zuverlässig hier auch mehreres bedeuten. Einmal, dass mindestens 1x im Jahr überhaupt Schnee fällt. Man könnte aber auch 2 Regionen vergleichen, in denen jeweils sehr sicher überhaupt Schnee fällt, aber in einer Region könnte es berechenbarer sein, wann, was für die Planung von Winterurlaub wichtig ist.